# JavaScript regexp replace $0

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have this jQuery, and I would like to search for a string and replace it. I know with php I can use `$0, $1, $2` etc. to get the matches.

This is how I would do this via php `$0` in this example would be replaced with the found `plater` and keep it's upper/lower casing:

```
preg_replace("/plater/i", "<span class='plater'>$0</span>", $input);
```

How can I do this in javascript? When I try $0 it actually outputs $0 to the browser, and not what was found. Here is what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = $("body").html();
    $("body").html(html.replace(/plater/ig, "<span class='plater'>$0</span>"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture it with parenthesis and use $1 to refer to the "first" capture group.

```
html.replace(/(plater)/ig, "<span class='plater'>$1</span>")
```

Guide to regex in several languages: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 2):

To replace a string:

```
html.replace(/(plater)/ig, '<span class="plater">$1</span>');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just searching for "plater" you could save yourself the trouble and just write the word `plater` in the string, but `$&` can be used to reference the entire match.

Comment: This won't match casing though will it?

Comment: @RyanNaddy `$&` should, but if you write out `plater` it won't.